# word frequency in a text field (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to find a certain word and its frequency in the field of type 'Text' in MySQL. Actually, I found a solution for that in Postgres  as follow:

```
SELECT word, count(*)
FROM ( 
  SELECT regexp_split_to_table(some_column, '\s') as word
  FROM some_table
) 
GROUP BY word
```

How can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: What you want, is basically the same only use `SPLIT_STR` instead of `regexp_split_to_table`

Answer (score 1):

Often, when this question crops up, the OP winds up using some application level code but, crudely...

```
SET @needle = 'the';

SET @haystack = 'the taming of the shrew';

SELECT @haystack, @needle, (LENGTH(@haystack)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@haystack,@needle,'')))/LENGTH(@needle)x;
+-------------------------+---------+--------+
| @haystack               | @needle | x      |
+-------------------------+---------+--------+
| the taming of the shrew | the     | 2.0000 |
+-------------------------+---------+--------+
```